# Waiting for a write stream to complete before returning a function

Tags: node.js, json, async-await, google-api

I'm trying to grab several JSON files from Google Drive, then export them into objects within my code. I am using a write stream to create the file locally and then parse it with `JSON.parse()`. This is my current implementation:

```js
function setDB(dbId, dbName) {
    let database = {};
    drive.files.get({
        fileId: dbId,
        alt: 'media'
    }, {responseType: 'stream'}).then(res => {
        console.log(`Writing to ${dbName}.`);
        const db = fs.createWriteStream(dbName);
        res.data.on('end', () => {
            console.log(`Done downloading file ${dbName}.`);
        }).on('error', err => {
            console.error(`Error downloading file ${dbName}.`);
            throw err;
        }).pipe(db).on('finish', () => {
            database = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./${dbName}`));
        });
    });
    return database;
}

let variable1 = setDB('variable1Id', 'variable1.json');
let variable2 = setDB('variable2Id', 'variable2.json');
let variable3 = setDB('variable3Id', 'variable3.json');
```

The issue here is `setDB` returns `undefined` since the function returns its value before the file finishes downloading and the stream finishes writing into the file. I understand that I should be using some kind of async/await, but I couldn't find how or where to place those. This might also not be the best way to go about this, and I'll gladly take any advice about making a better implementation of this, or making the code cleaner or more elegant. However, the main issue here is, how do I make it so that setDB returns `` JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./${dbName}`)) `` ?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code to return a promise that resolves on stream `finish` event and rejects on stream `error`. Your original code doesn't wait for your promise.

```js
function async setDB(dbId, dbName) {
  const db = fs.createWriteStream(dbName);
  const res = await drive.files.get({
    alt: 'media',
    fileId: dbId,
  }, {responseType: 'stream'});
  console.log(`Writing to ${dbName}.`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    res.data
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log(`Done downloading file ${dbName}.`);
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`Error downloading file ${dbName}.`);
        reject(err);
      })
      .pipe(db)
      .on('finish', async () => {
        try {
          const fileContent = await fs.readFile(`./${dbName}`);
          resolve(JSON.parse(fileContent));
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
  });
}
```